# Visual Studio for Mac miss .net6 for .NET MAUI after update

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-mac

After I updated my Visual Studio for Mac and installed .NET 8 preview, then I cannot create a MAUI with .NET 6.

You can see from the following picture, I can only choose .NET7 or .NET8.
[[image]]

**Detailed information:**

Visual Studio Community 2022 for Mac
Version 17.6.3 (build 421)

.NET SDK (Arm64)
SDK: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.100-preview.7.23376.3/Sdks

```
SDK Version:

8.0.100-preview.7.23376.3

7.0.307

7.0.304

7.0.302

7.0.200

7.0.102

7.0.100

6.0.413

6.0.410

6.0.408

6.0.406

6.0.405

6.0.403

6.0.402

6.0.401
```

What I have done:

Download and install [.NET6.0.21 ARM](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0) and in cmd use `dotnet workload install maui`. Then restart visual studio for mac.

How can I create a .NET MAUI with .NET6?

Comment: Did you install the MAUI workload with .NET 6? Can you check you have any .NET 6 project templates available for MAUI? There should be a microsoft.maui.templates.net6.*.nupkg file in /usr/local/share/dotnet/template-packs/

Comment: @MattWard Thanks and yes, I find many .net6 related nupkg files in that folder such as _microsoft.maui.templates.net6.6.0.550.nupkg_ and _microsoft.maui.templates.net6.6.0.553.nupkg_. Before I updated and installed .NET8, I can choose .NET6 and .NET7, but after that I can choose .NET7 and .NET8. .NET6 is missing. I used this way to install .NET8: [How to update](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-dotnet-maui-in-dotnet-8-preview-7/#how-to-update)

Comment: Interesting. I can repro. I tried step by step. Install .NET 6 only with MAUI. The install .NET 7 and MAUI. All good at this point. The install .NET 8 preview 7 with MAUI and then .NET 6 is not available. Only workaround seems to be to uncheck .NET 8 support in preferences and restart Visual Studio for mac.

Comment: The template engine seems to only use the .NET 7 and .NET 8 project template .nupkg files. You can see the files being used in the ~/.templateengine/vsmac/17.6.3/templatecache.json file.

Comment: I think this is how the templates work here. If you run "dotnet new maui -h" from the command line you see that only net7.0 and net8.0 are listed. If you try to use net6.0 it will fail. If you use a global.json file to pin to .NET 7.0 then whilst 'dotnet new maui -h' seems to not work, you can use 'dotnet new maui -f' which will fail and show that only net6.0 and net7.0 are valid frameworks.

Comment: Seems this is by design. The MAUI SDK only supports two versions of .NET.